# Rails cached column dont get updated on destroy - Has many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to count how many tags that belongs to konkurrancer. 
It is a has_many through Tagsmenu relation ship.

I have added the column konkurrancers_count to my Tags table.

Here is my join model:

```
class Tagsmenu < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :konkurrancer, :counter_cache => :true
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

But when I destroy a konkurrancer the konkurrancers_count column dont get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this methods: [update_counters](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/CounterCache/update_counters)

Answer (score 1):

if you `delete` a record it just runs the deletion sql.  If you `destroy` a record, it will instantiate the model, run all the callbacks, and *then* run the deletion sql.  I think you'll find that you need to use `destroy` in order to see the cache column update.